# How to accept parameters in a Python class constructor?

Tags: python, oop

```
class Druid:
    def __init__(self, Attack, Defence, Speed, Money, Crit):
        self.attack = DAP
        self.defence = DDP
        self.speed = DSpeed
        self.money = DMoney
        self.crit = DCC
    def Druid_stat(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.DAP, self.DDP)

Human_Druid = Druid(8, 7, 3, 50, 5)

print(Human_Druid.Druid_Stat())
```

then I get the errors of

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ianbrown/Desktop/Shannara_Cronicles_ALPHA.py", line 13, in <module>
Human_Druid = Druid(8, 7, 3, 50, 5)
  File "/Users/ianbrown/Desktop/Shannara_Cronicles_ALPHA.py", line 5, in __init__
self.attack = DAP
NameError: global name 'DAP' is not defined
```

It's probably really obvious and I've been comparing it to the tutorial code just with minor adjustments eg. class names and attributes etc.

Comment: What is DAP? Or DDP? Or self.DAP/self.DDP? It's not in the code

Comment: is it not in there at the point self.attack = DAP

Comment: You're telling it "set `self.attack` to `DAP`, but it doesn't know what `DAP` means. What is `DAP` supposed to be?

Comment: `NameError: global name 'DAP' is not defined` - that's the obvious part. It's actually telling you to define `DAP` before you can assign it.

Comment: Druid Attack power so in this case 8?

Comment: Python doesn't know what DAP or 'Druid attack power' is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> just with minor adjustments eg. class names and attributes etc.

You need to be super careful with naming. Python doesn't know what your variables mean or how to infer one name from the other.

It may be obvious to you that *Attack* has the same meaning as *DAP* - but that's just obvious to you, not to anyone else and certainly not to Python. All it sees are names that you give to things.

So I assume what you want to achieve is this (red arrows pointing from the constructor argument to the respective instance variable):

[image]

Right? To do this you have to keep consistent with naming:

```
class Druid:
    def __init__(self, attack, defence, speed, money, crit):
        self.attack = attack
        self.defence = defence
        self.speed = speed
        self.money = money
        self.crit = crit
    def Druid_stat(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.attack, self.defence)

Human_Druid = Druid(8, 7, 3, 50, 5)
print(Human_Druid.Druid_Stat())
```

Note I also changed the names in the constructor, the `__init__` method, to lowercase. While not technically required, it is a convention in Python to write variables in lowercase (as in `attack, defence` etc.), class names in `CapWords` form (e.g. `Druid`) and constants in all `UPPERCASE`.

Comment: thanks so much, i'm starting to think youtube tutorials are probably not the best now xD but thats cleared up a lot for me now

Comment: glad this helps. Indeed you might benefit from a course with proper structure - e.g. at [codeacademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/python). There are many offerings, and I'm not affiliated in any way. Here's [another one](http://www.learnpython.org/), a bit less formalized. Of course you can always pick-up a book if you're into that sort of thing, just search for e.g. _learning python book_

Answer (score 1):

This is not an OOP problem. You try to assign the variable DAP to self.attack but you never set DAP in the first place.

What I asume you are trying to do is:

```
self.attack = Attack
```

Attack is set to 8 when creating the object. You must do the same for the other variables as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor (the `__init__`), you are stating that your `Druid` class' variables are `attack`, `defence`, `speed`, `money` and `crit`.  NB: they being all lower case matters -- your constructor inputs (viz., `Attack, Defence, Speed, Money, Crit`) are different by virtue of the initial letter being upper case.

I do not understand why the `DAP`, `DDP` and the other `D` names show up, but they do not belong there.

Seems like you are trying to adapt an example from wherever you are reading, but you have done a hodge-podge of retaining some of what you read while changing other parts and gotten yourself into a good deal of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you're receiving seems to be coming from 'DAP' not being declared.
Try declaring these variables before the method, and giving the class the object type

```
class Druid(object):
    DAP = 0
    DDP = 0
    def __init__(self, Attack, Defence, Speed, Money, Crit):
        self.attack = DAP
        self.defence = DDP
        self.speed = DSpeed
        self.money = DMoney
        self.crit = DCC
    def Druid_stat(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.DAP, self.DDP)

Human_Druid = Druid(8, 7, 3, 50, 5)

print(Human_Druid.Druid_Stat())
```

You can also declare the variables inside of the init method,

```
class Druid(object):

        def __init__(self, Attack, Defence, Speed, Money, Crit):
            DAP = 0
            DDP = 0
            self.attack = DAP
            self.defence = DDP
            self.speed = DSpeed
            self.money = DMoney
            self.crit = DCC
        def Druid_stat(self):
            return '{} {}'.format(self.DAP, self.DDP)

    Human_Druid = Druid(8, 7, 3, 50, 5)

    print(Human_Druid.Druid_Stat())
```

And finally, I may be incorrect on this, but you're passing in values to the method, without them being used? So what you may be looking for is something like this:

```
class Druid(object):

        def __init__(self, Attack, Defence, Speed, Money, Crit):
            self.attack = Attack
            self.defence = Defence
            self.speed = Speed
            self.money = Money
            self.crit = Crit
        def Druid_stat(self):
            return '{} {}'.format(self.DAP, self.DDP)

    Human_Druid = Druid(8, 7, 3, 50, 5)

    print(Human_Druid.Druid_Stat())
```